# How to send DMR SMS using MMDVM modem or hackrf?

Tags: software-defined-radio, digital-modes, dsp, dmr

I have a baofeng DMR radio with SMS feature, and since there is not much DMR radio owners in my area I want to do something myself.

The easiest thing I can do I thought is to send myself some SMS as I did with a POCSAG pager using my hackrf one.

But I haven't found any software to do that. All I found is MMDVM-SDR program on github which acts as a MMDVM modem utilizing a fake serial port. It allows to get commands from the MMDVM-Host and modulate them as IQ WAV file.

There is one problem: that MMDVM modem protocol has no commands to send DMR SMS. It only accepts "DMR DATA packet" at different rates. I tried to google for "DMR AIR interface" but it also has no mentions of SMS.

By that time I learned that DMR SMS is a non-standartized thing which leaves me with this questions (one is part of the another):

- What format all those TYT and Baofeng radios is using, where I can get it's datasheet.
- How to make a DMR SMS packet for my radio and send it to a MMDVM modem emulator or directly to the SDR using some other modem software?

PS: I tried to record my radio's signal with SDR and play it back. With voice it works, I can hear myself, but with SMS it doesn't work for some reason: my radio just ignores them (maybe that is because it's number in both from and to fields?)

Answer (score -1):

Message sending is not part of DMR standard. Messages are transmitted in CSBKs, Control Signalling Blocks

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Please consider expanding your answer with a little more background and explanation.

Comment: What format do SMS take in a CSBK? I can find ETSI documents that explain how to go from a CSBK all the way to modulated RF, but I can't find a document that describes how I go from an SMS message to a CSBK.

Comment: How I said it is not part of DMR standard.

Comment: Right, it's not part of the ETSI DMR standard. But given that multiple radios handle SMS compatibly, it's plausible that there's another document (not the ETSI standard) that documents how you build a CSBK that represents an SMS